# How to filter data on DATE field in google sheet using ListQuery

Tags: java, url, google-sheets

I have a google sheet, Where there is a column as date which stores date in **dd-MM-yyyy** format. Using `java` i am trying to fetch records with a specific date for example i want records of **14/01/2016**. I have tried below code.

```
URL listFeedUrl = new URL(worksheet.getListFeedUrl().toString());
ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(listFeedUrl);

listQuery.setSpreadsheetQuery("date==\"14/01/2016\""); // Not working.
//listQuery.setSpreadsheetQuery("broadcastsubject==\"3-Minute Belly Tightening Trick\""); //Working fine.  

System.out.println(listQuery.getSpreadsheetQuery()); 
ListFeed listFeed = googleService.getFeed(listQuery, ListFeed.class);

System.out.println(listFeed.getStartIndex());
System.out.println(listFeed.getTotalResults());

for (ListEntry row : listFeed.getEntries()) { 

    System.out.println(row.getCustomElements().getValue("Date")+"=================="+report.getDate());  
    System.out.println(row.getCustomElements().getValue("BroadcastSubject"));
}
```

I have tried with broadcastsubject column name which is working perfectly, it gives me number of rows. but when i tried with date field it gives me 0 rows. Can anyone please tell me how to do this with date field....!!!